# Sage hangs when calling Mathematica

Tags: python, wolfram-mathematica, sage

I recently installed Sage 6.3 on my Fedora 21 machine. I'm using version 6.3, which is slightly outdated, because it is the most recent thing available in `yum`'s repositories. I also installed Mathematica on the same computer in the hope of being able to call it from within Sage.

Mathematica's terminal interface using the `math` command works, which according to [this reference page](http://doc.sagemath.org/html/en/reference/interfaces/sage/interfaces/mathematica.html) should be all that I need. However, when I tell Sage to use mathematica either from the Sage command line or the notebook, Sage hangs. Here's a sample of my interaction with the terminal (the traceback is horrible, as is frequently the case in Sage):

```
sage: mathematica('hello world')
^CInterrupting Mathematica...
^C---------------------------------------------------------------------------
KeyboardInterrupt                         Traceback (most recent call last)
<ipython-input-1-9208bb19d841> in <module>()
----> 1 mathematica('hello world')

/usr/lib64/python2.7/site-packages/sage/interfaces/interface.pyc in __call__(self, x, name)
    197
    198         if isinstance(x, basestring):
--> 199             return cls(self, x, name=name)
    200         try:
    201             return self._coerce_from_special_method(x)

/usr/lib64/python2.7/site-packages/sage/interfaces/expect.pyc in __init__(self, parent, value, is_name, name)
   1310         else:
   1311             try:
-> 1312                 self._name = parent._create(value, name=name)
   1313             # Convert ValueError and RuntimeError to TypeError for
   1314             # coercion to work properly.

/usr/lib64/python2.7/site-packages/sage/interfaces/interface.pyc in _create(self, value, name)
    387     def _create(self, value, name=None):
    388         name = self._next_var_name() if name is None else name
--> 389         self.set(name, value)
    390         return name
    391

/usr/lib64/python2.7/site-packages/sage/interfaces/mathematica.pyc in set(self, var, value)
    508         cmd = '%s=%s;'%(var,value)
    509         #out = self.eval(cmd)
--> 510         out = self._eval_line(cmd, allow_use_file=True)
    511         if len(out) > 8:
    512             raise TypeError("Error executing code in Mathematica\nCODE:\n\t%s\nMathematica ERROR:\n\t%s"%(cmd, out))

/usr/lib64/python2.7/site-packages/sage/interfaces/mathematica.pyc in _eval_line(self, line, allow_use_file, wait_for_prompt, restart_if_needed)
    535     def _eval_line(self, line,  allow_use_file=True, wait_for_prompt=True, restart_if_needed=False):
    536         s = Expect._eval_line(self, line,
--> 537              allow_use_file=allow_use_file, wait_for_prompt=wait_for_prompt)
    538         return str(s).strip('\n')
    539

/usr/lib64/python2.7/site-packages/sage/interfaces/expect.pyc in _eval_line(self, line, allow_use_file, wait_for_prompt, restart_if_needed)
    890                     out = ''
    891         except KeyboardInterrupt:
--> 892             self._keyboard_interrupt()
    893             raise KeyboardInterrupt("Ctrl-c pressed while running %s"%self)
    894         if self._terminal_echo:

/usr/lib64/python2.7/site-packages/sage/interfaces/mathematica.pyc in _keyboard_interrupt(self)
    420         e = self._expect
    421         e.sendline(chr(3))  # send ctrl-c
--> 422         e.expect('Interrupt> ')
    423         e.sendline("a")  # a -- abort
    424         e.expect(self._prompt)

/usr/lib64/sagemath/site-packages/pexpect.pyc in expect(self, pattern, timeout, searchwindowsize)
    914         """
    915         compiled_pattern_list = self.compile_pattern_list(pattern)
--> 916         return self.expect_list(compiled_pattern_list, timeout, searchwindowsize)
    917
    918     def expect_list(self, pattern_list, timeout = -1, searchwindowsize = -1):

/usr/lib64/sagemath/site-packages/pexpect.pyc in expect_list(self, pattern_list, timeout, searchwindowsize)
    965                     raise TIMEOUT ('Timeout exceeded in expect_list().')
    966                 # Still have time left, so read more data
--> 967                 c = self.read_nonblocking (self.maxread, timeout)
    968                 incoming = incoming + c
    969                 if timeout is not None:

/usr/lib64/sagemath/site-packages/pexpect.pyc in read_nonblocking(self, size, timeout)
    546                 raise EOF ('End Of File (EOF) in read_nonblocking(). Pokey platform.')
    547
--> 548         r, w, e = select.select([self.child_fd], [], [], timeout)
    549         if not r:
    550             if not self.isalive():

/usr/lib64/python2.7/site-packages/sage/ext/c_lib.so in sage.ext.c_lib.sage_python_check_interrupt (build/cythonized/sage/ext/c_lib.c:1683)()

/usr/lib64/python2.7/site-packages/sage/ext/c_lib.so in sage.ext.c_lib.sig_raise_exception (build/cythonized/sage/ext/c_lib.c:769)()

KeyboardInterrupt:
sage:
```

The equivalent in Mathematica's own interface works just fine:

```
Mathematica 10.1.0 for Linux x86 (64-bit)
Copyright 1988-2015 Wolfram Research, Inc.

In[1]:= hello world

Out[1]= hello world

In[2]:=
```

Am I doing something wrong, or is this a bug in Sage? Would downloading and building the latest version (6.7) manually fix the problem?

**EDIT**:

I am using Mathematica 10.1.0. Could it be that be my problem, i.e. the older version of Sage doesn't know how to handle the newer version of Mathematica?

Comment: I asked this question here because I know there's a small-but-active community of Sage experts. In some ways, it would be a better fit elsewhere - if the community thinks it should be moved, I will gladly cooperate with a migration to [SuperUser](http://superuser.com) or elsewhere.

Comment: True, probably better on SuperUser, though even less likely to be seen - ask.sagemath.org is probably best.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

According to [Trac 16703](http://trac.sagemath.org/ticket/16703), this problem should be fixed in the latest Sage.  I don't personally have a copy of Mathematica to test this on.

Comment: Thanks! I'll build the latest version when I get the chance.